# How many nozzles do Spider-Man's web shooters have in Marvel Spider-Man PS4?

Tags: marvel, video-games, spider-man

How many nozzles do Spider-Man's web shooters have in Marvel *Spider-Man* PS4?

Answer (score 4):

It's four [as can be seen in this screenshot from the game](https://marvels-spider-man.fandom.com/wiki/Web_Shooter?file=Web_Shooter_from_MSM_screen.png).

[image]

One main string and 3 *rotating* strings to create the iconic look for the webs.

[image]